# How to setup all module disable only quiz module is enabled in moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

my moodle application only use quiz module and other all functionality/module is disabled in moodle.

please help me how to set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to site admin -> plugins -> activity modules -> manage activities

Then hide/disable everything except the quiz module